# printing the total sum for a while loop in python

Tags: python

```
def main():
    import math
#the loop
choice=str(raw_input("Will you add an item to the list? Say 'yes' to add or 'no' once you're done"))
while choice== "Yes" or choice== "yes":
    addItem=input("What is the item?")
    additemP=input("How much does that cost?")
    print(addItem + "---------------------$" + additemP)
    choice=str(raw_input("Will you add an item to the list? Just say yes or no"))
if choice != "yes":
    quit
    total = sum(additemP)

    print(total)
```

every time i end the loop my output of the list shows the items i named and their price, but i can not get the total to print out i only get an error message

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' on line 14

I just started coding very recently and I'm not too sure what to do

Comment: Why are you using raw_input and input. If you are using python 3, just use input

Comment: I believe the ``loop`` should be in the ``main`` function. If so please indent the code accordingly. If it isn't, then you can get rid of the ``main`` function as it does not do anything.

Comment: @Silencer, I believe the **original code was meant for python2**. The **edited version is strictly python3** thus answers will loose some of the nuance for python2. ``raw_input()`` implicitly converts user inputs to strings. While ``input()`` accepts only  numbers. Passing an input that cannot be interpreted as a number to ``input()``  raises ``NameError``. Please redit the question to reflect the op's original meaning.

Comment: @XeroSmith  When I post the change, some I found someone has changed it. But I cannot cancle it, until it was peer reviewed.... I get it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making two mistakes here.

1. input() will return the string of whatever you type. So when you add in addItemP, which is the cost, its only a string and not an int. Hence, sum(addItemP) won't work. Convert it to int using int(addItemP)
2. You aren't using a list. Otherwise the total will only have the cost of the last item.

This should work.

```
def main():
    import math
#the loop
PriceList=[]
choice=str(input("Will you add an item to the list? Say 'yes' to add or 'no' once you're done"))
while choice== "Yes" or choice== "yes":
    addItem=input("What is the item?")
    additemP=input("How much does that cost?")
    PriceList.append(int(additemP))
    print(addItem + "---------------------$" + additemP)
    choice=str(input("Will you add an item to the list? Just say yes or no"))
if choice != "yes":
    quit

total = sum(PriceList)

print(total)
```

Comment: Thank you so much this really helps. I don't know very much at all about coding i'm only a student that just started learning, but this helps to clarify how some things work for me. +1

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a list.

```
choice=str(raw_input("Will you add an item to the list? Say 'yes' to add or 'no' once you're done"))
listofprices=[]
while choice== "Yes" or choice== "yes":
    addItem=input("What is the item?")
    additemP=input("How much does that cost?")
    listofprices.append(int(additemP))
    print(addItem + "---------------------$" + additemP)
    choice=str(input("Will you add an item to the list? Just say yes or no"))
    if choice != "yes":
       total = sum(listofprices)
       break
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use list because sum function use loop to add values like

```
sum([1,2,3,4])
```

or

```
 iter=[1,2,3]
 sum(iter)
```

Comment: The sum function does not take 4 arguments. The first part of the answer is incorrect.

Comment: i forget to put the [] around

Answer (score 0):

There is an Indentation error at the if statement it suppose to be

If choice !="yes":
      quit
Print(total)